# truncate in twig on html content

Tags: symfony, twig, truncate

I would like to truncate a long string, who content html tag.

From my controller php.

```
content="<div>
<h1>my title</h1>
<p>para 1 ...</p>
</div>";
```

I would like to truncate this, so i did this in twig :

```
{{ content|raw|truncate(15) }}
```

But the html are broken, see bellow :

```
<div>
<h1>my ti...
```

I want to keep the end of tag, like this :

```
<div>
<h1>my titl...</h1>
</div>
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you that you should keep the data separate from views. That is, pass the data in your twig file and put it in tags there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Twig Truncation Extension](https://github.com/bluetel/twig-truncate-extension). As you can read in the [doc](https://github.com/bluetel/twig-truncate-extension#truncating-on-character-count):

```
{% set html %}
    <h1>Test heading!</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Hello world</li>
        <li>Foo bar</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
{% endset html %}
{{ html|truncate_letters(20) }}
```

will output:

```
<h1>Test heading!</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Hello wo</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with the [text-truncate](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/typography/#description-list-alignment) class of [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

```
<h1 class="text-truncate">my title</h1>
```

If you don't want to use bootstrap, you can do it directly in css with the property [`text-overflow:ellipsis`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) as it is the case in [bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_text-truncate.scss).

[Here is an example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) in css.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: the css works but we don't push all the code in html view