# Symfony Twig | raw <div> tags destroy my design

Tags: twig

I use `|truncate(350)|raw` in twig to output content from db.
If there is some  tag inside and it truncates them, my design is broken.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [truncate in twig on html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839025/truncate-in-twig-on-html-content)

Answer (score 0):

ok - found some solution:

```
|striptags|truncate(350)|raw
```